# Problem adding an image to the toolbar using UIBarButtonItem, displaying blank white box instead of image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, toolbaritems

Im not sure what im doing wrong. The file name is correct, the style is set to plain. But Im getting a bank white box the size of my image. Im using UINavigationController.

Please assist and thank you thank you in advance.

**FYI I am sorta new to objective c so dont be too hard on me. ;)

```
 UIBarButtonItem *toolbarChannelGuideButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"channel-guide-button.png"]
     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
     target:self
     action:@selector(action:)];


self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:toolbarChannelGuideButton, nil];
[toolbarChannelGuideButton release];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason it was creating the white mask was because the `UIToolBar` doesnt allow color images on it by default. The way to accomplish this is creating a `UIImage` then assign a `UIButton` to that image. Then create a `UIBarButton` using `initWithCustomView` with the `UIButton` as the custom view.

**Code:**

```
     //Load the image   
     UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image.png"];

     //create the button and assign the image
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     //sets the frame of the button to the size of the image
     button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

     //creates a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
     UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];



     self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customBarItem, nil];
     [customBarItem release];
```

Comment: UIButtonTypeCustom fixed this for me. I was using roundedrect one

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 7 you can use below:

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD:)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Does channel-guide-button.png belong to project?

You could break this out like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"channel-guide-button.png"];
NSLog(@" image = %p", image);
UIBarButtonItem *toolbarChannelGuideButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithImage:image
     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
     target:self
     action:@selector(action:)];
```

or just check your project ;-)

Comment: I checked in my project and yes its in there. I also ran a NSLog it displayed a low level number.

Comment: image = 0x6b45340 is what it displayed in the console

Comment: Oh well. FWIW, I usually create UIBarButtonItem with initWithCustomView: and pass in UIButton with image associated with it. I'll post code example tomorrow.

Comment: No need to post example, I already figured that. Look at answer above. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Now im just trying to figure out how to position it center on the toolbar

Comment: Whats your real name westsider?